# iOS7 iAd - open banner ad and closes it crashed app

Tags: ios, iad

I have the following code in my `LibraryViewController` to enable iAd banner:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    if (!self.canDisplayBannerAds) {
        self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;
    }
}
```

iAd banner appears automatically at the bottom of the screen.  I clicked the banner, ads appear fine.  But when I close the ad, the app crashed with the following message:

```
[_UIViewControllerOneToOneTransitionContext isDescendantOfView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x166c6110
```

I have a `mainViewController` that switches view. `libraryViewController.view` is inserted as a subview at index `0` of the `mainViewController.view`.

Any idea why this happens?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you're treating a UIViewController as a UIView, which it most certainly is not.

Comment: I did not state clearly.  I inserted the libraryViewController.view as a subview of the mainViewController.view. Thanks for catching this.  Edited above.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the exception. You're somehow getting a `UIViewControllerOneToOneTransitionContext` called as a UIView. Which probably means the problem is somewhere in your storyboard transition methods.

Comment: I am not using storyboard. It seems like when the ad is closed, the previous view or view controller cannot be accessed any more.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed to using a ADBannerView and it works.  If I want to show ads on the inserted subview, it is better to use ADBannerView.